# AWK selection of the specified columns

Tags: bash, awk, numbers

I have a file fith big number of colums like

```
ASN   1 | R ASN   1 |    0.000 +/-  0.000 |   -0.000 +/-  0.000 |    0.045 +/-  0.034 |   -0.045 +/-  0.034 |    0.000 +/-  0.000 |    0.000 +/-  0.001
HID   2 | R HID   2 |    0.000 +/-  0.000 |   -0.000 +/-  0.000 |    0.001 +/-  0.002 |   -0.001 +/-  0.002 |    0.000 +/-  0.000 |    0.000 +/-  0.001
PRO   3 | R PRO   3 |    0.000 +/-  0.000 |   -0.000 +/-  0.000 |    0.001 +/-  0.004 |   -0.001 +/-  0.004 |    0.000 +/-  0.000 |   -0.000 +/-  0.001
LYS   4 | R LYS   4 |    0.000 +/-  0.000 |   -0.000 +/-  0.000 |    0.182 +/-  0.073 |   -0.176 +/-  0.072 |    0.000 +/-  0.000 |    0.005 +/-  0.003
MET   5 | R MET   5 |    0.000 +/-  0.000 |   -0.000 +/-  0.000 |   -0.004 +/-  0.004 |    0.006 +/-  0.004 |    0.000 +/-  0.000 |    0.002 +/-  0.001
```

from this file I need to extract of only first and last column removing from the last column error value (+/- value ) to obtain smth like:
ASN   1  0.000

its strange that below command works good with the exemption that it could not remove error from the last column

```
gawk -F'[|]' '{print $1, $NF}' $file 

ASN   1      0.000 +/-  0.001
HID   2     -0.000 +/-  0.001
PRO   3     -0.000 +/-  0.001
LYS   4      0.000 +/-  0.001
MET   5     -0.000 +/-  0.001
GLU   6     -0.000 +/-  0.001
MET   7      0.000 +/-  0.001
ILE   8      0.000 +/-  0.001
LEU   9      0.001 +/-  0.001
```

alternatively when I replace it with

```
gawk -F'[|,+/-]' '{print $1, $(NF-1)}' $file
```

it didn't replace column before last column (value) but did subtraction -1 from the last (error) column:

```
ASN   1  -0.999
HID   2  -0.999
PRO   3  -0.999
LYS   4  -0.997
```

what should I correct here to fix the script ?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex for field separator is wrong. Use like this:

```
gawk -F'\\||\\+/-' 'NF>1{print $1, $(NF-1)}' file
ASN   1      0.000
HID   2      0.000
PRO   3     -0.000
LYS   4      0.005
MET   5      0.002
```

i.e. use double escaping for regex meta characters like `|` or `+`.

#### [Code Demo](http://ideone.com/O0N9h0)

Comment: produced error OMP_OR2W1_linalol.dat FNR=5) fatal: attempt to access field -1

Comment: With your sample data, what I pasted here is the actual output I got from `gawk 4.1.1` btw using my BSD awk also this works

Comment: its real works only when I use $NF-1 but in that case it just substract ONE from  the LAST VALUE :)

Comment: You should use `$(NF-1)` not `$NF-1`

Comment: fatal: attempt to access field -1
:)

Comment: @user3470313 clearly you have empty lines in your file. Just prefix the action block with `NF` so it only executes on lines that aren't empty.

Comment: As suggested by @EdMorton, I added a safeguard condition `NF>` in the answer. Try again. btw did you check demo link?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `-F'[|]'`, you are stating that `|` is a field separator.  Using `-F[|+/-]` means you're using any of these characters as a field separator: `|`, `+`, `/`, or `-`.

You have two choices:

- Use spaces, but then understand that you need to calculate your columns a bit differently since `+/-` is now a column. I print columns 1, 2, and the third from the last.

For example:

```
$ awk '{printf ("%-5.5s %2d  %10.3f\n", $1, $2,  $(NF - 2))}' test.txt
ASN    1       0.001
HID    2       0.001
PRO    3       0.001
LYS    4       0.003
MET    5       0.001
```

- Or, you can use a fancier regular expression that says you want to separate fields via `*\| *` or `*+/- *`. Note I include the spaces in my regular expression field separator. This way, spaces are stripped from my columns:

Note my regular expression:

```
$ awk -F' *\| *| *\+/- *' \
    '{printf ("%-5.5s %2d  %10.3f\n", $1, $2,  $NF)}' file
ASN    1       0.001
HID    2       0.001
PRO    3       0.001
LYS    4       0.003
MET    5       0.001
```

This works with standard `awk` on BSD and `nawk` on Solaris. `gawk` might do things a bit differently.

Comment: its again produce error if I use $(NF - 1) and alternatively subtract 1 from the value of last columm if I use $NF - 1.   It seems problem with my AWK isn't it?

Comment: Are you cutting and pasting these commands from my answer? The first one works with no errors on GNU Awk 3.1.5 on RHEL. The second one gives me a warning that `|` and `+` will be treated as plain characters and not as special regular expressions. Otherwise, it works.

Comment: What machine are you using? What is your OS? Maybe you have an OS like Solaris where things don't work as they would on BSD or Linux.

Comment: The OS doesn't matter. He's using gawk, it works just fine. The OP needs to tell us more about his input file and what exactly the problems/errors are he's seeing.